# Vertically Centering text in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navigation bar displays the text at the very bottom. I think the VISA logo is conflicting  with it. Can someone help me vertically center the text?

I've attached a CSS file and an HTML file that I'm using. The words are currently at the bottom of the bar, which was been preset to be 67px in height (i don't know how to autoset the height of the navigation bar to vertically center the images and the text...

Thanks so much

```css
.navbar-default {
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, .05);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -moz-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
  max-height: 67px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #7a96ea;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #4169e1;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
  display: inline;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
  color: #7a96ea;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #7a96ea!important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
        <img src="img/upsidelogo.png" alt="UPside" style=" width:3%; min-height:auto; display:initial;">
        <img src="img/Visa.png" alt="UPside" style=" width:5%; min-height:auto; display:initial;">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#Mission">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#Features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#Join">Join</a>
        </li>
        <li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Environment Resources -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline;` from the following rule, the reason is that you cannot set the size on `inline` elements. So all of the fancy centering that bootstrap does would not apply.

```
.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
  display: inline;
}
```

It should look like this,

```
.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
}
```

Then add the following rules to your CSS, and remove the style attributes from the `<img>` tags inside `.navbar-brand`.

([Demo](http://jsbin.com/dijewidusi/edit?html,css,output))

```
.navbar-header {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.navbar-brand::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you link me a copy of your logo images?

Comment: hmm how do i do that?

Comment: anotehr link if the two images above don't work: http://imgur.com/HYeUeDL&HwSa7nv#0

Comment: I've updated my answer, please let me know if there are any outstanding issues.